# Problems with jquery tab styles when sidebar used

Tags: jquery, css

Usually my jquery tab styles work, but after adding a sidebar I've got no end of problems and got myself very confused.  I want the active tab to have a 2px black line on left, top and right, and NO black line underneath (ie white underneath).  I also need it's text to be red.  Unfortunately my active tab css style doesn't seem to control anything. Can anyone help?  Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0343rg8u/

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css


<div id="My_RH_BigContainer">
  <div id="RH_tabsContainer">

    <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="sidebar-img" style="display: block;">
        <label>Table 1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-img">
        <label>Table 2</label>
      </div>

      <ul id="RH_TabsTable" class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href='#Pivot1a_ws' rel="nofollow">Table 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Pivot2a_ws" rel="nofollow">Table 2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="TabContentID" class="tab-content">
      <div id="Pivot1a_ws" class="tab_pane"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>




#My_RH_BigContainer {
position: absolute;
height: 360px;
border: 1px solid red;
top: 20px;
left: 15px;
width: 500px;
}

#RH_tabsContainer {
Margin-top: 15px;
Margin-bottom: 5px;
Margin-left: 15px;
Margin-right: 15px;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 330px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}

.sidebar-img {
display: none;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 60px;
background-color: yellow;
border: 0px solid black;
}

.nav-tabs {
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
background: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
float: left;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
margin-right: 0px;
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
background-image: none;
outline-color: transparent;
border: 0px solid grey;
line-height: 16px;
font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
height: 20px;
width: 115px;
}

.ui-tabs-active{
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
color: red;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
background: white;
color: black;
}





$(function() {

  var index = 'qpsstats-active-tab';
  var dataStore = sessionStorage;
  var oldIndex = 0;
  try {
    // getter: Fetch previous value
    oldIndex = dataStore.getItem(index);
  } catch (e) {}

  $("#RH_tabsContainer").tabs({

    active: oldIndex,

    activate: function(event, ui) {
      //  Get future value
      var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
      //  Set future value
      try {
        dataStore.setItem(index, newIndex);
      } catch (e) {}

      $('.sidebar-img').hide();
      $('.sidebar-img').eq(ui.newTab.index()).show();
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: Your style is overriding by other css. Checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/0343rg8u/1/. I have added `!important` to make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67ms7m4t/3/

Explanation:

```
.ui-tabs-active{
border-style: solid;
border-color: black !important;
border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

I added *!important* after the border-color, otherwise this is overridden by your CSS. Note: try to use as less !importants as possible, otherwise you end up with very messy style overrides. (Everytime you do, god drives a user to start Internet Explorer. )

```
.ui-tabs-active a {
color: red !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Your red color needs to be applied to the `a` element, not the `.ui-tabs-active` element. Further, to let the active tab get rid of the grey border, we apply a white border to the bottom of our active `a` and move its `margin-bottom` by -1 (basic idea provided by @Ram Sergev in the answer below!).

```
#RH_TabsTable{
border-bottom: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
}
```

And finally the black border on bottom of the tab - this actually came from your #RH_TabsTable element. Not exactly sure if I understood you correct on this one, but I figured that you want the color of the inactive tabs. If you want no border at all (which looks weird), just give it `border-bottom-style: none`.

---

Side note: to debug stuff like this, try the developer tools of your browser. In chrome, you can simply right click the element (f.e. your TABLE 1 tab), choose INSPECT from the context menu, and see the styles in the bottom right. Here you see from which css source various css rules are coming and you can swap them live. This lets you understand how your page is processing its styles and saves you loads of time.

Comment: This is great but I still can't get rid of the bottom border line in the active tab (only).  I've tried using 'border-bottom-style: none;' but I still get the inactive tab bottom border showing under the active tab.

Comment: Updated the fiddle and answer, based on the idea by Ram!

Comment: Excellent and well-explained answer.  I'll perservere with the development tools next time

Answer (score 0):

You can add white background to the focused class and `margin-bottom:-1px`

Add this to your css

```
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus{
  color:red;
  border-bottom: #fff;
  border-width:1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

You can see it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzg117pf/)

Comment: Good idea, but I would avoid using a:focus: otherwise the white border is gone, once the user clicks into the actual content below the tabs.